# Best self study book with answers to selected questions for analytic number theory?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, book-recommendation

All:

Can anyone recommend Best self study book with  answers to selected questions for analytic number theory ?

If a book have no answers to questions, but if you know if some professors choose the book as textbook and post answers to selected questions online (as homework solutions), that will be OK too. In this case, can you please give the name of the book and the URL of the course/homework.

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Stopple - *A Primer of Analytic Number Theory*.

Answer (score 4):

There is a canonical best answer here: Murty's Problems in Analytic Number Theory is what you're looking for as a problem source.

It's nicely complemented by standard texts such as Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory or Montgomery and Vaughan's book.